# Why is the sample Unity ARcore scene not detecting planes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I installed the arcore-preview.apk on my Samsung 8(SM-G950U). Then I installed the sample ARCore scene from Unity onto the S8. The app starts up fine , but does not draw any point clouds or blue guidelines displaying the planes. I also cannot place the little Andy bot onto a plane. All I get is the UI saying, "Searching For Surfaces". Any ideas? I'll be continuously tinkering until I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to have been the version of Unity(2017.2.0b10) I was using. So I just went back to the Unity Beta Archives and downloaded 2017.2.0b9 and then downloaded Android Target Support specifically for 2017.2.0b9. All is now working correctly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the beta version 0b9, it won't work on the current stable one